# Why git doesnt give me any file changes?

Tags: git

Today I had wierd situation which I can not explain and scared that this will create a lot of troubles in future.

Me and my colleague, we are developing web site. We are using GIT and today after merge we saw that styles doesnt appear on site. After looking in the git log we saw that my commit where rewrite font.css file, and change fonts urls path on old variant(my fault). He push his changes in font.css again on git. I see his commit, pull it, but my font.css was not changed (still with old urls). okey, i changed it by my self and push it on git. When my colleague pull it, he had his own version of font.css, not my. We are using bitbucket and source tree. Does any one have any ideas what's wrong and how to prevent this situation in future ?

Comment: Did you use push or push -f?

Comment: Are ye using the same remote - Both do a git remote -v and verify

Comment: @gpullen The use of "ye" so betrays your nationality :)

Comment: Have a bad habit of typing the way I talk.....

Answer (score 0):

Check..

- You have included them correctly using `git add`
- You have correctly commited the files using `git commit`

If these are ok, you should be able to see the file on your repo, say on GitHub?

If you can see if on Github, you need to check the branches and your flow to make sure you commit and push/pull/merging from the correct places.

Not sure if this is an issue of your workflow? The only reason that they wouldn't be included would be that you didn't add the files in `git add` or they are in your `.gitignore` file therefore being excluded?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that both of you are working on different branches?

That is: when you (and or your colleague) pull from the remote, the changesets are downloaded, but they continue to reside in separate branches (e.g. `foo` or `origin/foo`) and are not merged into your working branch (e.g. `bar`).

A quick-fix is to manually merge the two branches:

```
git merge origin/foo
```

If you want to continue working on different branches, you ought to use a "deployment" branch (e.g. `master`) where you merge in all the changes you want to see on the actual target webpage (and don't have to worry about breaking it accidentally when pusing non-working code from your working-branch).

If you are confident enough that you won't break things, you might also just decide to have a single branch (`master`) where you and your colleague push to directly.

In any case you should make sure to setup your local branch to `track` the corresponding remote branch:

```
git push --set-upstream origin foo
```